# Tasker: switch on VPN when opening specific URL?

Tags: tasker

Tasker is an automation app for Android (see http://tasker.dinglisch.net/)

I want to start VPN whenever I start http://*.intra.mycompany.com - as intra.mycompany.com are urls that are just accessible over VPN.

Anyone knows how that could be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Tasker homepage there's a section called "Plans" where the developers outline future ideas that they might incorporate into the product: http://tasker.dinglisch.net/todo.html

Also listed on this page are those two lines:

> Actions/Tasks: VPN (dis/re)connect
>
> Events/States: VPN connected

So it's not included yet but it might be at some point in the future. Again citing from the page:

> This is an informal list of features under consideration for Tasker.