# Automate Always-On VPN with Tasker

Tags: tasker, vpn

I have a VPN server at home which works great with the built in VPN client from Android 5.1. I can also use my VPN server with the Always-On option, so no problems there.

I want Tasker to toggle the Always-On VPN option so that i can disable it when i'm connected to my home wifi network. Is this possible? I have a Nexus 5 with stock rom, no root.

Side-question: How to disable the Always-On notification message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VPN control isn't yet supported by Tasker, it's part of a todo list as mentioned in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9635/tasker-switch-on-vpn-when-opening-specific-url).

Comment: With all due respect, that answer is from 2011. So after 5 years we can conclude that VPN will not be supported by Tasker.

Comment: I'm going by what I see on the developer's page,  it isn't for anyone else to guess at his intentions.